# MVC5 printing multiple partial views in A4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, printing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application where I have need to print the "details" view to fit into a single A4 page, I've managed that bit with some CSS as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
@@media print {
    .printest {
        background-color: white;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 29.7cm;
        width: auto !important;
        min-width: 21cm;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0px;
        font-size: 9px;            
    }

    .dl-horizontal > dd:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
    }

        .container > div {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .container > dl {
            flex: 1;
        }

    dl {
        width: 100%;
        background: #ff0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    dt {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background: #cc0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    dd {
        float: right;
        width: 49.5%;
        background: #ff0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .maincolumns {
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
    }

    .no-print, .no-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }

    a {
        content: none !important;
    }

    button {
        content: none !important;
    }
}

@@media screen {
}

@@page {
    size: A4;
}
```

this works fine for a single page, but I have another view where I call multiple instances of said "details" page as partial and need to print those as well on A4 paper for each instance(partial view)

multiple detail view is as below:

```
 @@media print {
        .a4page {
            background-color: white;
            height: auto;
            width: auto !important;
            min-width: 21cm;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 9px;
            page-break-after:always;
            page-break-before:always;
            page-break-inside:avoid;
            float: none!important;
            overflow:visible!important;
            position:relative;

        }

    .printest {
        background-color: white;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 29.7cm;
        width: auto !important;
        min-width: 21cm;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 9px;
    }

    .dl-horizontal > dd:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
    }

        .container > div {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .container > dl {
            flex: 1;
        }

    dl {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #ff0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    dt {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background: #cc0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    dd {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        background: #dd0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .maincolumns {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .no-print, .no-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }

    a {
        content: none !important;
    }

    button {
        content: none !important;
    }
}
```

```
<h1>Details</h1>


<h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.FirstOrDefault().Name)</h3>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="a4page">
        @Html.Partial("Details", item)
    </div>
}
```

problem I'm having is that this all prints on to a single A4 page on top of each other making a huge mess, how do I resolve this and get each of these "Details view to print on their own page.

Answer (score 0):

You have positioning that aligns to top, left 0.

Try adding a div with style 'page-break-after: always' around each '.a4page', and remove the page break styling from the '.a4page' class.

Comment: I've tried removeing the positioning as well as adding the div with the style 'page-break-after: always' around the '.a4page' class divs as well as removing the styling from pagebreak a4page class, it seems to have gotten me pretty much the same result as before, will add more details to my post soon